# When passing a method's result as the argument to a function, when does that method get called

Tags: java

When is `User.toString()` called?

```
private JSONObject convert(String stringRepresentation) { --> A
   // Some code here.
   // This is when we actually do something with "stringRepresentation":
   someMethod(stringRepresentation); --> B
}
```

Usage:

```
JSONConverter.convert(User.toString());
```

Is the `User.toString()` method called right after `convert(String stringRepresentation)` has been invoked (A), then it's value remembered and whenever needed, used right away OR is `User.toString()` called at the moment down the code of the method where `stringRepresentation` is actually used(B)?

Comment: You don't pass a method, you pass a value calculated basing on the method.

Comment: Immediately, as you don't pass a reference to a method but a method result.

Comment: From JLS 15.12.4: _"At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. **Second, the argument expressions are evaluated.** Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is located. Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a method is called, all of its arguments are evaluated from left to right.

Quoting [section 15.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4) of the JLS:

> In a method or constructor invocation or class instance creation expression, argument expressions may appear within the parentheses, separated by commas. Each argument expression appears to be fully evaluated before any part of any argument expression to its right.

Also, they are evaluted before the method is actually invoked. Quoting [section 15.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) (emphasis mine):

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. **Second, the argument expressions are evaluated**. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is located. Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code.

As such, `User.toString()` will be invoked before the method is called.

Answer (score 3):

As a `convert`'s actual parameter, its being called (once) right before calling `convert`.